# How to add the search box value to URL

Tags: javascript, html, view

I have the html view where It is a search bar as a string. The code of needed part is below.
So, how correctly put value from the search bar to the URL string?
Can I do this only with html or I need to use js?

```
<form class="navbar-search navbar-search-dark form-inline mr-3 d-none d-md-flex ml-lg-auto" method="get" 
action="/search/" >
                <div class="form-group mb-0">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" id="mySearch" placeholder="Search" type="search" value >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>.
```

Comment: If you're using html and JS alone you would have to preventDefault on the search form and use window.location.href to construct the desired URI. What are you currently doing? That will help us give a more focused answer

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how this works with forms, maybe this helps get you closer?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#dynam-now').click(function () {
console.log($('#mySearch').val())

});
});

</script>

<form class="navbar-search navbar-search-dark form-inline mr-3 d-none d-md-flex ml-lg-auto" method="get" 
action=$('#mySearch').val()" >
                <div class="form-group mb-0">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" id="mySearch" placeholder="Search" type="search" value >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <button id="dynam-now">Click to search</button>
```

Comment: i saw this but i dont know how to implement it - <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function initInput()
 {
 var variable = somevalue;
 document.forms[0].fid_17.value = variable;
 }
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="initInput()">
 <form>
 <input name="fid_17" id="fid_17" value="">
 </form>
</body>

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/write-a-variable-to-a-form-input-value/1196